# Map discrete numeric to string

Tags: r, dictionary

Similar to this one on [dictionary in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2858014/1568919), but my index (or key) is integer. So I have a vector c(1,1,44,44) and a mapping (1 -> US, 44 -> UK) and how can I get a vector of (US, US, UK, UK)?

The normal named vector method doesn't work.

```
> a = c('US','UK')
> names(a) = c(1, 44)
> a[44]
<NA> 
  NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

names(a) is a character vector so you use the quotes

```
a['44']
  44 
"UK"
```