# Working with dictionaries/lists in R: how to get the values from the key-value pairs?

Tags: r, dictionary, hashmap, lookup

This is related to [Working with dictionaries/lists in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858014/working-with-dictionaries-lists-in-r), where we try to create a key-value style dictionary with vectors, but now about how to access the values.

I can get the keys in the following way

```
foo <- c(12, 22, 33)
names(foo) <- c("tic", "tac", "toe")
names(foo)
[1] "tic" "tac" "toe"
```

and I can access the elements

```
> lapply(FUN=function(a){foo[[a]]},X = 1:length(foo))
[[1]]
[1] 12

[[2]]
[1] 22

[[3]]
[1] 33
```

and then I can do

```
unlist(lapply(FUN=function(a){foo[[a]]},X = 1:length(foo)))
[1] 12 22 33
#or 
sapply(FUN=function(a){foo[[a]]},X = 1:length(foo))
[1] 12 22 33
```

but this is very inconvenient. How can I conveniently access the values in the format `c(12,22,33)`? Is there some ready convenient command for this in R?

Comment: I assume you meant 12, not 11?

Comment: @Calimo yes, fixed, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you mean `foo[1]` or `foo["tic"]`? your final function could be written `unlist(lapply(FUN=function(a){foo[a]},X = 1:length(foo)))` or more simply as `sapply(FUN=function(a){a, X = foo)`.

Comment: @Imo Calimo already answered probably with the most simplest solution. I did not know the function `unname` that perfectly works here. Thank you Calimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have these values in `foo`; they only have [a `names` attribute](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/names.html) which has no impact on the data structure itself. Any function expecting a numeric vector will work perfectly fine, regardless of the names.

If you want to remove the names, just say:

```
unname(foo)
```